# Draw square by reading X,Y coordinate from

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas

**Updated**
here is my code that I'm working on. My code is Javascript with PHP. I’m 
reading X,Y Coordinates from MySQL Database to then be able to draw a rectangle at 
the position given.

I have 3 fields in my table coordinates: coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord. It has 5-6 
rows.

In my code I’m testing with one square first and it works. Now, I want to loop through 
the Database by the use of multidimensional arrays so I can draw all of the rectangles.

Thank you in advance it’s much appreciated!

Javascript with PHP:

```
<div class="section_a" >
                <p>Section A</p>

                <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="500"></canvas>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var ctx, cv;
                    cv = document.getElementById('imageView');
                    ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';

                    <?php
                 $select_coordinate_query = "SELECT * FROM coordinates";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$select_coordinate_query);

                        //see if query is good
                        if($result === false) {
                        die(mysqli_error()); 
                        }

                        //array that will have number of desks in map area


                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  

                            //get desk array count
                           //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP**
                            $desk = array( array("x" => $row['x_coord']),
                                         array("y" => $row['y_coord']) 
                                         ); 

                //x, y coordinates 
                            $x_pos = $desk['x'];
                            $y_pos = $desk['y'];
                            //x,y width and height
                            $x_size = $x_pos + 40;
                            $y_size = $y_pos + 10;    
                     //HELP**
                    ?>
                    ctx.strokeRect(<?php echo "$desk[x]";?>, <?php echo "$desk[y]";?>,100 , 100);                   
                    <?       
                        } //end while loop
                    ?>
                    </script>

            </div> <!-- end div section_a -->
```

Comment: So.. you're asking for help in how to query mysql? how to get data from mysql into php? how to get php to draw your chart? You should step back and look at the bigger picture - doesn't matter **WHERE** the coordinates come from, they're just coordinates and you need to write drawing code that can handle them. And the DB itself couldn't care less that they're coordinates. they're just numbers.

Comment: Maybe try using svg to draw your squares. You would need some sort of formula to figure out sizing of each square though

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. no I know how to query and all. I was just lost. I posted my code and now i'm trying to use multidimensional arrays to read every coordinate from my table

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp)

Here is an example :

```js
var c = document.getElementById("container");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


// size of a "desk"
var desk = {
  width: 40,
  height: 15

};

/* simple desk example */
// coordinates of your desk
var coords = {
  x: 20,
  y: 20
};

ctx.rect(coords.x, coords.y, desk.width, desk.height);
ctx.stroke();


/* multiple desks example - in blue */

// coordinates of each desk
var desks = [
  { x: 20, y: 100 },
  { x: 130, y: 115 },
  { x: 200, y: 130 }
];

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "2";
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
for (var i = 0; i < desks.length; i++) {
  ctx.rect(desks[i].x, desks[i].y, desk.width, desk.height);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
#container {
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="container" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Would the person that downvoted be kind enough to explain why? :/

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but the OP "appears" to ask for (1) MySQL access code plus (2) visualization code preferably using divs but alternatively using canvas. I say "appears" because OP talks mostly about DB access code but they have no MySQL tag on their question.  A pure guess: the downvoter desired your answer to also include the DB access code?? Anyway, here's +1 for (IMHO) furthering the cause of the question by answering the visualization half of the question using canvas.

Comment: thanks I updated the content and put some code now. I'm having problem looping through with multidimensional arrays. thanks in advance!